# Ansible - Error "MODULE FAILURE" on Windows hosts

Tags: ansible, winrm

I'm trying to use Ansible but I have a problem with some Windows hosts. When I start my playbook, I have the following message on this hosts but I don't understand why.

**Error Message :**

```
fatal: [XXXXXXX.DOMAIN.COM]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false,
 "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "", 
"module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}},
 "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}
```

**Variables ansible :**

```
ansible_user: admin@DOMAIN.COM

ansible_password: Password

ansible_connection: winrm

ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos

ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

ansible_winrm_port: 5986
```

I checked if my config WINRM was good. My **listener HTTPS is configured** and I have the rule **WINRM HTTPS** for port **5986 activate**

Comment: Have you already increased the ansible verbosity `-vvvv` to see if it will provide more details about what specifically failed?

Comment: Yes, I retried for be sure but there is no more details with -vvvv